# fetch values from three tables and compare all three value with single table

Tags: mysql

i am facing problem in creating mysql query.it bit complicated but i will try to make clear. I have four tables like:

- 1)farmer_details
- 2)disrtrictlist
- 3)blocks
- 4)village.

I have three known values

> disrict(id),block(id),village(id) from table disrtrictlist blocks village

Firstly I want fetch these three field from these three tables then i want to find these three values contain in farmer_details tables.if you understand and have any suggestion please provide help.

i write these query but it doesn't work for me:-

```
select 
    farmer_name,
    father_name,
    district,
    centre,
    land,
    farmer_details.village,
    mobile 
from farmer_details
    ,disrtrictlist
    ,blocks
    ,village 
WHERE disrtrictlist.name_id  LIKE '6' 
    AND ( blocks.id  LIKE '53' and village.id LIKE '2')
```

Comment: Read about joins. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: We need to see the table structure to be able to help you.